# How to resume dialogue

Tags: watson-assistant, watson-dialog

Currently I can resume a dialogue with the primary node, I developed an action in my application that gets context and when I put in the dialog: "I want to resume my service", the action takes the context and puts it in Watson and so resumes the service, but this does not work when I want to resume from a child node

Can I resume a dialog on a child node with the Watson conversation?

Comment: Add more details and maybe an example. Depending on the API it should be possible.